# Get records in mysql database that have dates which will be due in the coming 2 weeks

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause, date-arithmetic

i want my code to retrieve rows that will be due in the less than 2 weeks so that i can send a reminder to the user to renew there subscription

```
$Q = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE dateDue BETWEEN (dateDue - INTERVAL 2 WEEK) AND NOW()";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be:

```
select *
from records
where dateDue > now() and dateDue <= now() + interval 2 week
```

Or, if your date has not time component (that is, you have a `date`, not a `timestamp`):

```
select *
from records
where dateDue > current_date and dateDue <= current_date + interval 2 week
```

Your question does not mentions whether you want inclusive or exclusive intervals. You might need to adjust the inequalities accordingly.

Comment: Thanks i want it to show all records that will be due in the the next two weeks or which are less than two weeks or which are more than two weeks

Comment: @jamesphiri: this brings record whose `dueDate` is between now and two weeks in the future, which is how I understood your question.